standard Basis of finite dimensional dual space is algebraically independent.
let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over field $K$ and $V^*$ be it's dual. Consider $\{x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n\}$ to be standard basis of dual space.
If $K$ is infinite then we can do it by induction on number of variables.
For base case if we have a polynomial $P(x_1)=0$ implies that $P \equiv 0$ since it will have only finitely many zero.
assume for $n-1$ variables that if $P(x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_{n-1})=0 $ implies $P \equiv 0$.
For $n$ let $P(x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n)=0 $ this implies that if we apply any $v \in V$ then  $P(x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_{n-1})=0$ by above hypothesis $P \equiv 0$.
I want to know that is it right and how do we proceed for finite fields?

This does not generalize for finite fields. Take $n=1,K=\mathbb{F}_2$ and $P=T^2-T$.

could you please tell me is the proof for infinite field right or not.
